# Intellij IDEA: Can I have custom variable's in my run configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

Usecase:

I've found no [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com) plugin for Intellij IDEA. And I think I don't need one. If only I'd have the option to have each run/debug run ask for the parameter. For example, Rubymine has a rails generator shortcut which asks which generator to call before actually doing it. It'd like to have something like this in my grunt run configuration. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? You can edit run configuration in IDEA, just select `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...`, this lets you specify command line params, too.

Comment: yeah, but I want the param to be different each time. I could create like 10 configurations for each possible param. But it would be nice to insert a variable and have me enter it (via dialog box) when running the configuration.

Comment: I don't have any experience with IDEA and gruntjs, but when I run my Java project I can simply choose `Run...` (not `Run`!), then `Edit Configurations...` in the context menu that will appear, then insert the parameters and here you go :) Is that enough?

Comment: Nope. I need that parameter to be variable from run to run. In Eclipse, this is done by inserting a variable called `${string_promt}`, which opens up an dialog to ask the user for that variable value when the configuration is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that although it's not possible in the Run/Debug Dialog, it is possible with External Tools: *Settings -> External Tools -> Add an External Tool* and then as parameter `$Prompt$`.

Comment: ...and then you can choose `Before launch -> Run external tool...` in `Run/Debug` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like Eclipse's `${string_prompt}` in IDEA (as far as I know). My version is 12.1.6.

Anyway, you can scroll to the very bottom of Run/Debug configuration screen and in "Before launch" section check a checkbox saying "Show this page".

From now on you'll be automatically shown configuration screen after you click Run/Debug button.